# How to connect multiple servers to a client in Java using Sockets?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I'm doing a program by sockets, from a single client to multiple servers, on the internet I have not found information about this

The system consists of connecting multiple servers to a single client, the client must request a number from a user, then, in the server, with that number an algorithm will be executed that will find the number of prime numbers between 0 and N , afterwards, the execution time of the algorithm is calculated, and then sent to the client. Each time of each server is sent to the client and the client stores them.

The problem is that this connection must be simultaneous between the number of servers to be desired, in addition to this connection being synchronized.

For the moment, I have made a simple code, from a client to a server.

**MAIN SERVER**

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server s = new Server(5000, "Hilo servidor");
    s.start();
    }

}
```

**MODULE SERVER**

This is a method that is inside the server class, this class executes the algorithm to count how many cousins there are and to send that time to the client. It runs when calling c.start () in the main server

```
private void startServer() {

            try {
                ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);
                System.out.println("Esperando Conexion");
                Socket socket = ss.accept();


                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                int n = in.readInt();
                long time = encontrarPrimeros(n);
                DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                out.writeLong(time);
                System.out.println(time);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
}
```

**MAIN CLIENT**

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Client c = new Client("Hilo cliente", 5000, "192.168.0.19");
            c.start();
    }

}
```

**MODULE CLIENT**

```
    private void startClient() {
            try {
                    Socket socket = new Socket(ip, port); 
                    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());


                    System.out.println("Ingrese dato...");
                    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                    int n = scanner.nextInt();
                    out.writeInt(n);
                    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                    long tiempo = in.readLong();
                    System.out.println(tiempo);
                    socket.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
    }
```

The problem is, how can I connect several servers to a client, so they start synchronized?

Thank you

**Update**

I have modified the client's main method, because of this:

```
public class Main {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Client c = new Client("Hilo cliente", 5000, "192.168.0.19");
    Client c2 = new Client("Hilo cliente", 5000, "192.168.0.19");
    c.start();
    c2.start();
}
```

}

But when executing, I get the following error:

```
mar 23, 2019 7:14:10 PM Client startClient
GRAVE: null
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readLong(DataInputStream.java:416)
    at Client.startClient(Client.java:69)
    at Client.run(Client.java:41)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The instruction where the error is executed is the following: `long tiempo = in.readLong();`

Comment: Which is it? Single server, multiple clients as per your title? or single client, multiple servers, as per your question?

Comment: @user207421 A client, multiple servers connecting to that client

Comment: Sorry, the title has already been corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, in socket programming:

- a client can only connect to one server
- a server can receive many client connections
- The client manages his connection to the server through a socket object

If your client needs to connect to many servers, the client must create as many socket objects as the number of servers. And in order to manage the communication in parallel, you can create a separate thread on which you manage the IO for each socket.

So applied to your scenario:

- you can keep your Client class as it manages one socket
- you create N objects of the Client in the number of servers (you associate each Client instance with only one server)
- you can make your Client class runnable (by inheriting from Thread class).
- you run your Client as a thread (you can place the startClient() class in the protected void run() method that you inherit from Thread).
- In your main you call each client object start() method (inherited from thread). this will run the run() method in background.
- to collect all the results, you call join() on each Client object

**Client Class Example**

```
    public class Client extends Thread {

    private String ip;
    private int port;


    public Client(String serverIP, int serverPort) {
        this.ip = new String(serverIP);
        this.port = serverPort;
    }

    private void startClient() {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket(ip, port); 
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            System.out.println("Ingrese dato...");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            int n = scanner.nextInt();
            out.writeInt(n);
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            long tiempo = in.readLong();
            System.out.println(tiempo);
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.getStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        startClient();

        super.run();
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
Client client1 = new Client("192.168.1.100", 8888);
    Client client2 = new Client("192.168.1.101", 8888);
    Client client3 = new Client("192.168.1.102", 8888);

    client1.start();
    client2.start();
    client3.start();

    try {
        client1.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        client2.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        client3.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Server Class**

```
public class Server extends Thread {


ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

//Private class
class ClientSocket implements Runnable {

    private Socket m_socket;

    ClientSocket(Socket sock) {
        m_socket = sock;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(m_socket.getInputStream());
            int n = in.readInt();
            long time = n;
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(m_socket.getOutputStream());
            out.writeLong(time);
            out.flush();
            System.out.println(time);
            System.out.flush();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}


@Override
public void run() {
    startServer();
    super.run();
}

private void startServer() {

    try {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(8888);
        System.out.println("Esperando Conexion");

        do {
            Socket socket = ss.accept();

            threadPool.execute(new ClientSocket(socket));

        } while(true);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: That is, what are you propodiendo is the following?:
`public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client c = new Client("Hilo cliente", 5000, "192.168.0.19");
        Client c2 = new Client("Hilo cliente", 5000, "192.168.0.19");
        c.start();
        c2.start();
    }`

Comment: however, it would be better to take the scanner code outside the client's startClient method and supply the standard input value to all clients before connecting them to servers.

Comment: If I have understood you, the biggest problem is that I get an error when I try to execute, the error is in the instruction long tiempo = in.readLong(); of the method StartClient `(java.net.SocketException: Connection reset)`

Comment: Actually I was referring to the part of code where you read N (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); int n = scanner.nextInt();) >> It is better to read N only once and give it to Client in the constructor. Do you have a socket error when you read tiempo? I thought that part was okay.

Comment: Yes, although each client can give a different number, then this is why I do not pass it to the main thread of the client `(Main)`. No, that line releases an exception when executed, in this case, 2 instances of the client.

Comment: I think connect reset is due to server closing the connection. can you add a call out.flush() after out.writeLong(time) in the server to make sure the long number is returned before connection is closed? otherwise add a Thread.sleep() just to make sure the connection is not closed immediately by the server.

Comment: If I add the `Thread.sleep`, the object `c1` if it can execute the socket correctly, however, `c2` can not execute it correctly, and executes the error in the same instruction of the last time. In `Thread.sleep`, no matter how long you enter it as a parameter, you will execute the error on the object `c2`

Comment: I think you do not manage multiple client connections on your server. I updated my comment with the server class to create a thread for each connected client.

Comment: This does not break the rule that the same client connects to multiple servers ???. Basically, what I have to do is in that link: https://pastebin.com/8ZVzrCtQ

Comment: Not at all! We have here multiple clients connected to the same server. So we are good. I think the question you asked is quite misleading in the beginning because you said 1 client and several servers but finally you do have 1 server and several clients :-)

Comment: A client can connect to as many servers as it likes. Do you mean a client *socket* can only connect to one server?

Comment: @user207421 Exactly, the client can connect to N servers.

Comment: @HichemBOUSSETTA Thanks, one last question, can you explain how `ExecutorService` works? Is it an implementation superior to typical Threads only implementing `Runable` and `Thread`?

Comment: Executor service is a thread pool; meaning the service creates threads beforehand or on demand, and use them to execute runnable tasks. It is used to optimize thread creation. You can learn more about them by reading official documentation.